# Div content is not showed in right place because before div has position: relative

Tags: html, css, position

I have such code:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div style="float:left; width: 183px; background-color:#c1cba9; color: #000000;"><img border="0" alt="Product categories" title="Product categories" src="graphic/categrieshead.png" width="179" height="43"><br />
        <div style="margin-left: 10;">Links goes here</div><br />
        <img border="0" src="graphic/catbot.png" width="179" height="17"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 480px; height:100px; text-align: center;"><img border="0" src="graphic/description.png" width="232" height="81"><br /><div style="text-align: left; margin-left: 10;">asasasas</div></div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 322px; height:100px; text-align: center;">
        <div style="width: 300px; color: #ffffff; background-color:#6b8861; font-size : 34px;">Item title</div>
        <div style="width: 300px; color: #ffffff; background-color:#6b8861;"><div style="width: 296px; margin: 2 2 2 2; background-color:#ffffff;">Item picture</div><div style="width: 300px; height: 2px; background-color:#6b8861; color: #6b8861;"></div></div>
        <div style="width: 300px; color: #801010; font-size : 60px;">Price: 20£</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to add div which content (text) would appear under those three divs, but by simplyb adding it text appears not in right place (out of boundries in right side), how could I add div after my mentioned part that it would appear under that part in preview?

Comment: This question could probably benefit from an image showing how you want it to display. [It's kind of hard to tell what you're going for here.](http://jsfiddle.net/T6ELN/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an element with `clear:both;` after your floating elements:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

After this you could insert your new content div, and it will be below the others.

Comment: It worked, but with problem: when one of mine mentioned code is longer then others (has bigger height) as example now it's third div, most right, then added div with your code appears under first two, but not under third.

Comment: then wrap your new (added) div in another div that doesn't have a float property.

Comment: Wrapped with div without properties, still same

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right you have to add the new div's CSS `clear:both`.